# Connecting to an SQL Server User Defined Function from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have created an Inline Table-Value User Defined Function in SQL Server

I would like to input the parameters in various cells in an Excel spreadsheet, and have a table that will update with the results from those parameters when I enter them.

Normally, I do this with Microsoft Query, but that doesn't allow me to call a User Defined Function. So how do I go about creating an odc file, or otherwise connecting to that function?

I am using Excel 2010 and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this same problem.  You need to use VBA and ADO to call the function with parameters via a SQL query.

[This link shows how to make the call for a scalar function.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic919889-391-1.aspx)

A table value function would be similar, but you'd have to return the data as an array/matrix to call it directly from an Excel cell.   Alternatively you can [follow the directions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120674/accessing-sql-database-in-excel-vba) to use .CopyFromREcordset() and put the results into a worksheet.

Comment: +1 this answered my question - I'd have marked your answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
select dbo.YourFunction()
```

for a scalar UDF, or:

```
select * from dbo.YourFunction()
```

for a table-valued UDF?  MS Query might complain it cannot display the query graphically, but you should be able to enter it in SQL mode.

Comment: I cannot then add parameters to it, though. It complains that `Parameters are not allowed in queries that cannot be displayed graphically`