# How to retrieve data from a SQL Server db

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm writing a code snippet in VBA to pull data from a SQL Server 2008r2 database.  However, I'm getting a error at Conn.Open: **[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]**.

Using [ConnectionString.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#p2) and another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120674/accessing-sql-database-in-excel-vba), I've written this:

```
Function GetAddress() As String
    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Set Rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=12.34.5678;" & _
                            "Database=OurDB;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypw;"
    Conn.Open

    Set Rst.ActiveConnection = Conn
    Rst.Open "Select top 1000 * from MainTable"
End Function
```

[Googling](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1659580-named-pipes-provider-could-not-open-connection-sql-server.html) the error suggested that the Named Pipes might be Disabled.  Following that lead, I checked the SQL Server Configuration Manager and Named Pipes are quite Enabled (3rd order behind Shared Memory and TCP/IP).

How do I make this error go away? Am I using the right connection string?

Comment: Stupid question:  Error 53 is `Cannnot find network path`; is your Server path correct?

Comment: What is the value of `OurDB` at the time the code is run?

Comment: Are you referring to the server by IP?

Comment: There is a check list for this error here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: @Hansup, yes, I'm referring to the server by IP.

Comment: @JimmyPena, that value is the name of the database inside the SQL Server.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, Yes, I pulled the IP aka Server path directly from SQL Server.

Comment: Found the problem! What I thought was the server "IP" is actually the version of SQL (10.50.2500). Changing it to the name worked.  @Hansup, if you post your comment as an answer, green check for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check this part of your connection string:

```
Server=12.34.5678
```

It looks like referring to the server by an IP address, but it's not an IP address.