# Error 3709 when connecting thru ADODB.connection to SQL Server 2008 in Excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, adodb, vba

I'm trying to open a recordset on a SQL Server in Excel using the below code, but get a `3709 - The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.` error.  Where am I going wrong?:

EDIT:

It is now working, i'll update the code below:

```
'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVER\SERVER; Database=we_ci_db; Trusted_Connection=Yes"
    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSQL = "select * from tblUsers"

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

'Copy Data to Excel'
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

Comment: The string itself wasn't wrong, I've tried several combinations which are completely different, but all work.  It was the `rst.open` line that I didn't have right.  I needed to use the other attributes, cnn, adOpenStatic etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remou pointed me in the direction of an alternative Connection String, but I still got the same results.  I googled around for a bit and came up with another SO Question [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120674/accessing-sql-database-in-excel-vba) with a different implementation, which resulted in:

```
'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVER\SERVER; Database=we_ci_db; Trusted_Connection=Yes"
    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSQL = "select * from tblUsers"

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

'Copy Data to Excel'
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the connection string you need. it should read something like:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=SERVER\SERVER;Initial Catalog=cs_db;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

See http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: I've updated to the fields/values you've specified and it still says [3709 - The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.]

Comment: I see you have MS Access, can you link to a table? Is this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839428 relevant?

Comment: You don't believe you can link to a table?

Comment: Sorry, didn't answer your comment properly.  I can link to the table in Access, either via VBA or manually.  I do not believe that support item has anything to do with it.

Comment: Are you saying that the connection string you are using works in MS Access but does not work in Excel?

Comment: I've updated the question.  It would appear it wasn't the connection string that had the problem, but the implementation of the recordset.  Thanks for your time.