# Excel VBA Disable message "Uploading to..." when saving to Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, message, vba

We have developed a client / server solution in Excel 2010 VBA. The Excel Database is hosted on a hidden document library on a SP 2013 Server. The client is a local workbook containing the data entry form.

We want to maintain secret the path to the hosted DB. The issue is that whenever the user commit changes via a dedicated VBA routine a pop-up message with title "Uploading to the server" is displayed with in message body: "Uploading..." and the full path of the server DB.

We have included all standard message disabling functions in Excel VBA:

*Application.DisplayAlerts = False*

and

*Application.ScreenUpdating = False*

but they do not have effect on this type of messages. Wondering if they are actually from Excel? They may come from IE or WebDAV? In any case they are displayed only when saving is taking some time.

The SP hosted DB is opened and closed as follows:

---

Workbooks.Open \OurIntranet\services\ContractsDatabase_hidden_\LIVE_DB\Database v01.04.xlsb, , False, , MyPwd

Application.DefaultSaveFormat = xlWorkbookNormal

- UPDATING LINES -

wbk.Close

---

I have seen that also with DB hosted on a Network File Server the same message appears. So message box does not seem to be of SP origin.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and show us SharePoint-relevant parts of the "dedicated VBA routine" so that we can determine the set of libraries used. The message certainly does not come from WebDAV as this is a data-only protocol with no own UI

Comment: Ok question edited. As you see there are not "SP relevant" parts. The .xlb database is opened from VBA is the standard way. I start to believe these messages are actually from Excel but how to hide them?

Comment: If the message comes as built-in feature of the Excel (quite likely) you can succeed in hiding it by hiding the workbook and very likely by hiding complete Excel application. See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display

Comment: Ok thanks - I'll give this a try. However I cannot hide current workbook as the user should still see something on screen. Neither can hide the Excel app. Instead it may work if I open the DB in a separate (and hidden) Excel instance as advised in the post you linked. Thanks!

Comment: In your attempt to "_..maintain secret the path to the hosted DB.._" one thing worth considering might be moving the DB from the Excel-file-on-a-network-share format to a more typical DB client-server concept with user authentication etc. see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120674/accessing-sql-database-in-excel-vba

Comment: Yes, definitely. We used the approach we were more familiar with but clearly treating the DB as an actual DB via SQL queries would be surely more elegant and likely faster. We will give it a try, thanks!